# Input Dimension to TensorFlow LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I've looked at answers to similar questions to mine but I'm still confused about why exactly the input dimension to an LSTM is [batch_size, number_hidden_units].

The data itself and has the form [batch_size, number_of_features].

We want the output from the LSTM to have dimension [batch_size, number_hidden_units].

Let's ignore, for simplicity, the job that the LSTM gates play. Then, it seems the LSTM just needs to encode the input vector by multiplying it with a weight matrix of size [number_features, number_hidden_units].

Why can't this be done, and thus, the input be any dimension? What am I overlooking?

Edit: I just realized TF documentation says the input is indeed [batch_size, number_features]. I had read otherwise elsewhere.

Comment: Don't you mean "the input dimension to an LSTM is [batch_size, number_of_features]"? [batch_size, number_hidden_units] isn't how the input should be shaped.